# Copy a dependent table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this customers table (I'm using SQL Server):

[image]

About 300 customers were registered in this table. I created another table in another database and inserted these customers into the new database.

Here is the new customers table:

[image]

But I have an operation table as well and I didn't change this one. The problem is the foreign key here. Since `PhoneNumber` is no longer the primary key in `Customers` table, `customerId` shouldn't be filled with the phone number anymore. I want to know how can I insert about 1000 operations in the new operation table but use each customer's ID as a foreign key instead of phone number in `customerId`.

Here is the operations table:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume that `AFDB` is the old database and `StoreDB` is the new one, the following query helped me out:

```
    INSERT INTO StoreDB.dbo.Operations
    SELECT  StoreDB.dbo.Customers.Id, TypeID, Amount, [DateTime]
    FROM AFDB.dbo.Operations JOIN StoreDB.dbo.Customers
    ON StoreDb.dbo.Customers.PhoneNumber = AFDB.dbo.Operations.CustomerId;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query to update the old data in operation table:

```
UPDATE OperationTable AS OT SET CustomerID = 
   (SELECT ID FROM CustomerTable AS CT WHERE CT.PhoneNumber = OT.CustomerID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Counter in the old database is same as CustomerId in new database.
In your previous operations table of the old database, write a query like below

```
select 'Insert into OperationsTable values(
    ' + CT.Counter + ',
    ' + OT.TypeID + ',
    ' + OT.Amount + ',
    ' + OT.DateTime + ')' as newquery from OperationTable OT left outer join Customers CT on CT.PhoneNumber=OT.PhoneNumber
```

This will give you the insert queries which can be copied and run on the new OperationsTable in the new database

Now - if the above assumption is not correct - then -
You will have to write a query on the new customer table to insert the new Id from new customer database into the Counter Column (or a new CID column) of the old customer database, and then repeat the above step.